# How to unmount and then safely remove USB in windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have three WD external drives and I use WD Quick View to detach HDDs when I need to. What it does is, it finishes operations/flushes the drive, powers down the disk (stops the rotations), the LED goes off, and Windows chimes the drive removal sound. Essentially, the WD QV, stops power to the USB port. Is there any way one can do this to all the USB ports for flash/HD Drives?

Answer (score 3):

You want to find the "Safely Remove Hardware" icon in the system tray, and when clicked it will provide a menu allowing you to eject individual devices:

[image: Eject Hardware Menu]

<sup>[(Source)](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-safely-remove-hardware-windows-so-you-dont-lose-your-data)</sup>

In versions prior to Windows 10, the icon appeared as a USB plug with a green checkmark.

You can also right-click on a removable drive in Windows Explorer and select "Eject" from the menu:

[image: Eject from Windows Explorer]

Comment: I request you to read the details of the question. I know what you have illustrated and that is NOT what I am asking for,

Comment: @Dr.UrvishMistry I'm confused; Your question asks how to safely unmount and remove any USB mass storage device, to which I believe I have provided the answer. If you feel a specific detail was not addressed, please specify which detail as I read the question thoroughly the first time, and re-reading it has turned up no new information.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the Question Details, I want the drive to power down before ejection, like it does with WD Quick View. The default Windows ejection system does not power down the drive. It just simply unmount it. The drive still spins and LED remain on when ejected with Windows. While WD QV, it stops the power to USB port, the drive stops spinning. LED goes off. So, is there ANY way I can achieve this with thumb drive or other HDDs?

Comment: No. Maybe if you wrote a custom program, but other than that, not really, no. I'm not sure why you would want to actually power-down a thumb drive before removal, and while it's not the same as a full power-down, Windows will retract the heads and spin down the platters on a conventional HDD when it's ejected and there's nothing reading from it (even if it's still plugged into the USB port).

Comment: Okay. Windows MAY be retracting heads, but does not spin down the platter. Why I need this? Because I have an old WD Elements, which is not supported by WD Quick View.

Comment: It’s up to the drive to decide what to do when ejected. Windows has no business with that. Most USB hard drives would indeed power down when ejected. A USB port *cannot* be switched off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I am just going to make an answer.

You can use *[USB Safely Remove](http://www.safelyremove.com)*, as it seems to have the functionality you are requesting like powering off USB flash drives and HDDs. Why you would need this for flash drives is beyond me, maybe you can enlighten me.